# Charts and manipulations on html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do manipulations on html code.

I have this code:

```
<div id="LinesPlace" class="inlineBlock">
<div id="ExpensesId_2" class="width100 inlineBlock ExpensesViewList" style="border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;">
    <div class="width4 cbViewList">
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cbExpensesView[]" value="2" class="cbExpensesView" id="cbExpensesView_2">
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="width26 categoryViewList">
        <span>
            <img id="" class=" floatA inlineBlock" src="/Interface/Images/ExampleCategory.png" alt="category icon">
        </span>
        <span class="E_CatName Food">Food</span>
    </div>
    <div class="width20 dateViewList"><span>14-09-2015</span></div>
        <div class="width20 amountViewList">
            <span>2 $</span>
        </div>
        <div class="width20 repeatedViewList">
            <span>Repeated: none</span>
        </div>
    <div class="width10 noteViewList" style=""></div>
</div>
<div id="ExpensesId_3" class="width100 inlineBlock ExpensesViewList" style="border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;">
    <div class="width4 cbViewList">
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cbExpensesView[]" value="2" class="cbExpensesView" id="cbExpensesView_3">
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="width26 categoryViewList">
        <span>
            <img id="" class=" floatA inlineBlock" src="/Interface/Images/ExampleCategory.png" alt="category icon">
        </span>
        <span class="E_CatName Food">Food</span>
    </div>
    <div class="width20 dateViewList"><span>14-09-2015</span></div>
        <div class="width20 amountViewList">
            <span>2 $</span>
        </div>
        <div class="width20 repeatedViewList">
            <span>Repeated: none</span>
        </div>
    <div class="width10 noteViewList" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Now i as you can see i have div with "LinesPlace" id and there i got alot of divs (ExpensesId_2,ExpensesId_3...and so on...).

I want to create charts that get all the categorys type (like Food,Phone and so on..) and get all the amounts, if one category display more then one time we do sum (for example if we have 2 Food lines with 2$ each i need to get Food in the labels and 4$ in the data)  i got that example with hard coded:

```
var barData = {
                labels: ["Food","Phone","Clothing"],
                datasets: [{
                    fillColor: "#8f37b1",
                    strokeColor: "#8f37b1",
                    data: [100,155,500]
                }]
            }
```

How i manipulations it in javascript/jQuery to get the like that?

Please help =]

Regards,
Rafael jr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you're proposing, you will need to use a script to parse the contents of the page.  The good news is that your HTML is well structured for it - you have repeating sections with classes and tags that break up the data.

What you'd do is create a new, empty array and object.  Lets call it `expenseArray` and `expenseTotals`.  Create a jQuery selector like this:

```
$("div.ExpensesViewList")
```

Now you have a set for all the expenses.  You can now iterate over this array with .each.

```
$("div.ExpensesViewList").each(function(){
    //Parse the contents of the Expense
    //Add the values you found from each item to a new object in expenseArray
    //Add values to any existing values in expenseTotals
});

//Add expenseTotals to expenseArray as a final element in expenseArray
```

You'll want any given row in expenseArray to be the same kind of object as you create for expenseTotals.  When you're done, this becomes a final entry in the array.

Now that you have all this data in an array of objects, you can loop over the array and create charts, graphs, or whatever you'd like from the data.

I have to ask the question - where does the data in the html come from to begin with?  If it's being generated by some script on the web server, it will be a lot easier to get the data from the server in json format and skip parsing it all out of the page.  If you're hand coding the data in the page, it would make more sense to create an array of data and then create the html and charts from your array instead of the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the help =]
I get the Lines list from the Server side (php), but i get it build-in html i mean i return block of html, all the list html built in the php ..:D
sould i change it ? i can change it and then the list will be build in the javascript , its worth that?

Comment: I would, absolutely.  Here's why: separation of concerns.  Your PHP can generate the data in JSON and return that to your page, or to an app, or to any number of other interfaces that then do whatever they like with it.  The recipient can then present that data as needed.  The PHP and the data requestor need to know nothing about each other except for a data format.  In your case, your own web page can generate summaries, HTML structures, tables, charts, graphs, or anything else you desire from the JSON.  If you need to change - like adding tables in addition to HTML - It's far easier to do.